# Key reference book on toric ideals: normal or not? Which definition to follow?

Tags: reference-request, ideals, toric-geometry, reference-works

I want to understand sum of binomials better in terms of ideals such as binomial ideals, normal ideals and so by toric ideals. Examples about toric ideals contain $$\sum x^\alpha+\sum x^\beta\in\mathbb R$$ where $\alpha,\beta$ are multidegrees. I have a gut feeling that toric varieties and this [Sparse elimination theory](https://math.berkeley.edu/~bernd/sparse_elimination.pdf) is crucial to understand features of $\sum x^\alpha+\sum x^\beta$ deeper such as its negativity and positivity conditions. By ideal-variety correspondence, I think this question is related to [Reference request: toric geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/451752/reference-request-toric-geometry) while vaguely on [Finding generators of toric ideals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1317974/finding-generators-of-toric-ideals). [Sturmfels](http://arxiv.org/pdf/alg-geom/9610018.pdf) considers toric ideals in $\mathbb C$ and acknowledges the fact that Cox preassumes toric ideals to be normal while the work uses some other definition. So

**Does there exist a "bible" reference work on definitions on binomial ideals, normal ideals and then to toric ideals?**

Answer (score 1):

Fulton may be one of the earliest publication on toric varieties. It contains analysis on lattice points in polytopes and toric varieties.

*References*

- W. Fulton, Introduction to toric varieties, Annals of Math. Studies, Vol. 131, Princeton University Press, 1993.

*Examples about applications*

- Toric ideals and toric ideals of graphs [here](http://www.chtatakis-mathnet.gr/images/research.pdf)
- In the contex of contingency tables and markov bases such that $z=z^+-z^-$ so binomial $u^{z^+}-u^{z^-}$ where $u^{z^+}=\prod_i u(i)^{z^{+}(i)}$, $u^{z^-}=\prod_{i,j} u(i)^{z^-(i)}$ such that $z^+$ is the positive part while $z^-$ is the negative part -- source page 6 [here](http://mypages.iit.edu/~as2014/talks/hara-IIT140520.pdf). Toric ideal is defined as $I_A=\langle u^{z^+}-u^{z^-}; Az=0\rangle$.

*Other threads*

1. [Has toric ideal something to do with torus?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1737154/has-toric-ideal-something-to-do-with-torus) where algebraic geometry, toric geometry and gluing binomials to get toric ideals